# Persistent query result over MVC4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

Good morning,

I am working on new MVC4 apps which consist of a huge search form (more than 50 parameters).
After the form is submitted, a complex query is built and i obtained a IList of a viewModel:

```
IList<ResultViewModel> results = session.CreateSQLQuery(ComplexQuery).SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ResultViewModel>()).List<ResultViewModel>();
InterfaceVM.QueryResults = results;
```

InterfaceVM is then the model used by my output views to display grid results and Leaflet maps.
Everything works fine except that i can get results up to 1 million records.  I would need to implement paging using PagedList.MVC for example but without having to pass the search parameters in the URL. I would like to avoid rebuilding the query and the IList object again and again.

```
InterfaceVM.QueryResults =results.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 20);
```

Moreover, this IList results will also be used several times in my output views to generate dynamically complex GIS outputs.

I spent several hours reading over the web to find the best strategy to keep my result object persisting after the form has been submitted to be able to manipulate it easily and avoiding to rebuilt it for each paging/mapping request.
I read about **temp table** in SQL server, **Session object**, **MemoryCache** etc... but i don't know what would better fit my situation.

Your input on this would be really helpful. I am using Fluent NHibernate, MVC4, SQL server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance for your help

Sylvain

Comment: I can suggest ViewBag object. Read more about it. Hope it will help you